# How can I reverse the order of the street number and name in some of my contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

I have Google Contacts with addresses where the street address has the street name followed by the street number.  For example, instead of **`14 John Ave`** it is shown as **`John Ave 14`**.

I see the same issue in apps that access Google Contacts, like Gmail.

I think this may be a localization issue because in many EU countries, the **`Street`** [postal addresses format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address#Address_format) is **`name number`** whereas in North America it's **`number name`**.

Is there a way to switch the order of the street address in affected contacts?

Answer (score 0):

The [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) documentation shows how the information for each `Person` (contact) is stored.

> **[Resource: Person](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#resource:-person)**
> Information about a person merged from various data sources such as the authenticated user's contacts and profile data.

`streetAddress` is a field within an [`address`](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#address) object that contains no additional objects or fields, only a string. For example, `14 John Ave` or  , `John Ave 14`, or nonsense like `10 Supercalafragilistic Bob 1 seventy 9`.

In other words, whatever string/value you store in the `streetAddress` field is what is displayed and Google Contacts does not interpret it based on user's locale or otherwise.

You would need to manually edit these strings if you want to change them.  You could export your contacts and use a Google Sheets formula to modify the `streetAddress` string.